# Multi-variable correlation analysis (multiple linear regression possibly)

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression

I am doing a project for work that is deeper in the realm of statistics than I am used to and would like some help making sure the results I present are indeed relevant and correct.

We are looking at our marketing mix and trying to identify which marketing programs are resulting in the best sales lift.

Currently I have my data set up as follows (1 indicates inclusion; i.e., bucket 1 products were included in Ad Type 1, 2, and 3):

[image: Crappy Image due to work firewall restrictions on Imgur; Sorry!]

Below is a sample of the data:

```
    Bucket | Ad Type 1 | Ad Type 2 | Ad Type 3 | # of Products | Q4 - Q1 % Increase
       1   |    1      |      1    |      1    |       2       |    16.9%
       2   |    1      |      1    |      0    |       1       |    3.0%
       3   |    0      |      1    |      0    |       7       |    11.9%
```

Overall, I have 23 Buckets and 7 ad types each containing a different number of products.

The Q3 - Q4 % increase is there as a "baseline". There were a variety of different ads running during Q4 but I did not include those in this analysis as I do not have access to all of the necessary data.

Q1 is when the recorded ads were run.

I am trying to determine which "mix" is best. In other words, I am trying to determine which ad type correlates the most with an increase in sales.

I did a quick R-squared analysis between the ad type and the Q4 - Q1 Sales % Increase and got the following results:

```
Ad Type 1: 0.02 
Ad Type 2: 0.07 
Ad Type 3: 0.04 
Ad Type 4: 0.01 
Ad Type 5: 0.01 
Ad Type 6: 0.00 
Ad Type 7: 0.11
```

This is part of a larger analysis. I had already hypothesized that Ad Type 7 would have the greatest correlation. Since there are so many variables involved, 0.11 seems to show at least more correlation than some of the other variables.

I would appreciate any help in my approach and any further steps I could take to determine correlation or the best mix possible.

Comment: Buckets = groups of products, right? That would mean one ad type runs for many different products, correct? Interesting: Bucket 17 products have no ads but still a 7% and 6% increase.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: Yes Denwid, that's correct. Essentially I'm trying to help my company better allocate budgets to different advertising opportunities. My first step is to try to correlate the ads with overall business growth. Then I will dice into the more successful ad types to identify what within each of those ad types is working and how we can further optimize. It does make sense that some products grew with no ad inclusion due to natural market growth and shared product detail pages (might be a black shirt with no ads that's shares a page with a green shirt that is included in some ads).